# Validating HTML5 forms through the use of the DATA property

Tags: php, html, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating my first web form using HTML5 and Bootstrap 3. I am doing client-side validation UI on the form with a cross browser polyfill called 'js-webshims' (my target audience is IE8).

I've never done server-side validation before. Can I hook up this [server-side Bootstrap validation tool](http://ceres.bignold.com/validate/) using [data-] properties in HTML or is there much more work that needs to be done?

This is my demo form that I'm going to test:
[DEMO FORM](http://ogmda.com/3dms-public/form.php)

Comment: We need more information to help you. Can you post your PHP code? Your question isn't clear what you're trying to do